# webapp and django framework

Tags: google-app-engine

As far as I understand, the "Getting Started" guide of GAE with Python uses the webapp framework. However, it seems like it uses Django to render templates.

Does that mean that I can use the Django template engine without using its application framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sure can, you'd just need to have Django installed and import it. More information on using the template language outside of... say, render_to_response, can be found [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context).

If you like how the Django template language works, but don't want the rest of Django, you might want to check out [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/). It's -only- a template language and has a syntax similar to Django's, but is much, **much** faster and gives you "raw" access to Python in your templates (which is both a good and bad thing).